# How to limit my progress bar percentage to 100% only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is when I tried to run it and try to change tab in browser and back again the percent is more than `100%` as final result. But if i dont change tab while the progress is running it works perfect.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 .container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var progress = setInterval(function () {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width() >= 400) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width() + 40);
    }
    $bar.text($bar.width() / 4 + "%");
}, 800);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5w5ku/1/

Comment: Works good if you're not relying on the elements `width()` when calcualting the percentage: See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5ku/135/). Obviously (Firefox in my case) suspends the transition but not the timer, so the time your timer runs it gets the wrong value (when removing the transition in your example, it also works correctly ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just set to it a limit, this will work :

replace this row :

```
$bar.text($bar.width() / 4 + "%");
```

with this row :

```
$bar.text(Math.min($bar.width() / 4,100)+"%");
```

Comment: `-1` Your answer perfectly workarounds the symptoms of TO's problem _but not its cause_ (see my comment).